# Installing MantisBT on WSL2

Tags: wsl-2, mantis

I have installed MantisBT in Ubuntu in wsl2, I had no problem following the instructions like in another ubuntu server (unless for enabling ufw), but at the moment of open the browser to proceed with the installation I just see the contents of the file index.php.
[index.php in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBIDU.png)

I'd try to search information about installing mantisBT in wsl without success, so that is why I come here to ask if anyone had successfully installed MantisBT in Ubuntu in Wsl or you have any clues to try to resolve this.

This is my apache confid file,

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mantis"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mantis-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/mantis-access_log" combined
        <Directory "/var/www/html/mantis/">
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a missing php package, so first make sure you have all the packages require, I found this thanks to the mantis-error_log file, In my case was php-fpm. but just installing it does not do the trick, yo have to install it, start the service and restart apache2

```
sudo apt install php7.x-fpm
sudo service php7.x-fpm start
sudo service apache2 restart
```

One thing I may have forgot also, was to change the permissions of the mantis folder

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/mantis
```

and finally I made some changes in th conf file and system32/drivers/host
to make it work at its own URL. This was just improvemnt, not really part of th problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mantis"
    ServerName mantis.test
    ServerAlias www.mantis.test
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mantis-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/mantis-access_log" combined
        <Directory "/var/www/html/mantis/">
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

system32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mantis.test
::1 mantis.test
```